# Video site php oop or procedural

Tags: php

First of all, I'm beginner. I've start working only a month ago. I'm currenlty waiting to begin a project. It is a video website. I need second opinion. Should I process that project procedural or object-oriented way? What is your sugestion? I have to mention I've create past websites only procedural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a subject of personal preference. Are you doing it alone or in a team? It sounds like it going to be a one man project, and because you ask a question like this I think your smallest problem will be this. Then I should choose the one I feel more comfortable. Do you know OOP or it's only an idea because you read it? If you don't really understand OOP yet and if you do it in OOP you will probably end up in procedural code, wrapped in fancy class names. I saw lot of these kind of code, and it's a maintenance nightmare.

So, **if you know OOP** then do it in OOP.

If you don't really understand how OOP works, then do it in **procedural style** (or take time to learn OOP), because you dont' want to be your own enemy.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct! I kinda know OOP,but I'm far more comfortable with procedural style. I've done that way before. My only dilema was because eventual later changes on that wwebsite. It is much more easier to change php code later when it's in oop way. I have only one more question,how much time do I need to learn oop to be capable to this project oop style?

Comment: It is much easier to change if the system is well-designed and correctly layered. And it's true that OOP provides more to do it. I don't know how much time it takes for you, it really depends on you. You will know it when you will be there. So, when it's unequivocal for you to do it in OOP (because it's easier for you) then that's the time :)

Comment: thank you very much for your answer! I'm deeply grateful for your advices.